# Fibonacci problem, exceeding the maximum value of int

Tags: javascript, int, max, fibonacci

I m trying to solve https://www.spoj.com/problems/FIBOSUM/ problem.

```
MOD = 1000000007;

function copy(a, b) {
    a[0][0] = b[0][0];
    a[0][1] = b[0][1];
    a[1][0] = b[1][0];
    a[1][1] = b[1][1];
 }

function multiply(fib, base) {
    let mat = [[], []];
    copy(mat, fib);

    mat[0][0] = (fib[0][0]*base[0][0] + fib[0][1]*base[1][0]) % MOD;
    mat[0][1] = (fib[1][0]*base[0][0] + fib[1][1]*base[1][0]) % MOD;
    mat[1][0] = (fib[0][0]*base[0][1] + fib[0][1]*base[1][1]) % MOD;
    mat[1][1] = (fib[1][0]*base[0][1] + fib[1][1]*base[1][1]) % MOD;
    copy(fib, mat);
}

function calcMatrix(fib, n) {
    const base = [[1,1], [1,0]];
    fib[0][0] = 1;
    fib[0][1] = 0;
    fib[1][0] = 0;
    fib[1][1] = 1;

while (n) {
    print(n);
    if (n&1) {
        multiply(fib, base);
    }
    multiply(base, base);
    print('bef', n)
    n = n.toString(2).slice(0, -1); //same as n = n >> 1;
    print('aft', n)
    }
}

let t = parseInt(readline());
while(t--)
{
[N, M] = readline().split(' ');
N = Number(N);
M = Number(M);
let fib = [[],[]];
calcMatrix(fib, N);
let fn = fib[0][1];
let fn1 = fib[1][1] ;

calcMatrix(fib, M-N+2);
// (a%mod -b%mod +mod)%mod
let sum =  ((fib[0][0]-1)*fn + (fib[0][1]-1)*fn1 + MOD) % MOD;
print('wyni', sum);
}
```

There is my solution https://ideone.com/25HLU7. For n = 78 the result is correct, higher values make result exceeding max int. I can t use BigInt(), because of spidermonkey.

Comment: then you can't use javascript ..  once your int is over MAX safe integer, you're limited ... but your reason not to use BigInt is flawed - spidermonkey can handle bigint for over a year

Comment: When I`m trying to use BigInt on ideone, I get error: 'BigInt is not defined'

Comment: whats ideone? how is that relevant to spidermonkey

Comment: Ideone is online compiler. For javascript its using spidermonkey version 60.2.3, same as SPOJ..

Comment: oh, right, then you can't use BigInt :D